# I use <colspan> to merge 3 column (20% each) in one (60%) but they don't

Tags: html

I want to make a table using `<colspan>` and `<colgroup>`, but I don't get the need result.

```
<table border="2px">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="20%">
        <col width="20%">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">60</td>
        <td colspan="2">40</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">20</td>
        <td colspan="4">80</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

My result: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGD2TG4Q6EQL

Comment: Very odd, but seems to be because you never use the full width - adding in a header row of all 5 cells makes it behave properly. not sure if this is expected behaviour though. Update: does what you expect in Firefox - seems to be a Chrome issue

Comment: I noticed that if add all 5 column everything works fine. But why?

Comment: Not a clue I'm afraid - potentially a browser bug. Perhaps have a Google, see if anything comes up about this. Otherwise report a Chrome bug perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code on Linux in Firefox and everything work fine! So it the problem in the browser not in the HTML code.